# GATE how to annotate each verb except those in the list

Tags: java, gate

I have this task: I have .lst file in GATE with list of verbs. The have annotation Inner_predicates. And I need to annotate other verbs as Outer_predicates. Can you help me to write this rule?

I tried this:

```
Phase:  Outer_Pred
Input: Morph Inner_Pred
Options: control = appelt

Rule: Outer_Pred

(
    ({Morph.pos == verb}, Morph.baseForm !=Inner_Pred)
):tag
-->
:tag.Outer_Pred = {rule = "Outer_Pred"}
```

But it is of no use. How can I find a verb, check whether it already has an annotation Inner_Pred and if not, annotate this verb as Outer_Pred?
In inner_pred.lst I have list of verbs in base form.

Thanks in advance. And also it would be great, if you could tell me where I can look this information by myself. I found only [GATE Jape Manual](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/GATE%20JAPE%20manual.pdf) but it is quite short and doesn't provide many answers.

Comment: First the user guide: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html, then this repository: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/jape-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of verbs in their base form, you should try a [flexible gazetteer](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch13.html#x18-33800013.6). It will create "Lookup" annotations where it matches (not only on verbs).

Then to match each verb that is not on the list:

```
Phase: Outer_Pred
Input: Morph Lookup
Options: control = appelt

Rule: Outer_Pred (
  {Morph.pos == "verb", !Lookup.majorType == "yourInnerPredType"}
):tag
-->
:tag.Outer_Pred = {rule = "Outer_Pred"}
```

This will match every "verb" which does not start on the same offset as a Lookup with major type "yourInnerPredType".

Also, make sure you have the Morph annotations with the right pos feature.

Comment: Buy the way, I've got a question about JAPE syntax: is there any difference between "!Lookup.majorType == "yourInnerPredType"" and "Lookup.majorType != "yourInnerPredType""? Or they will work well in all cases?

Comment: {Morph.pos == "verb", Lookup.majorType != "inner"} requires there is a Lookup annotation on the same position as the Morph (and its majorType to be different from "inner"). 

The syntax in the answer does not require a Lookup annotation, it says "Even if there is a Lookup annotation, it shouldn't be with majorType == inner", opposed to "There must be a Lookup annotation with majorType != inner"

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple JAPE rule using Java in RHS which will:

a) take any verb (Token.category==VB | Token.category==VBD | and etc). List of possible verb POS tags you could find at the end of GATE tao.pdf

b) take start and stop nodes of this Token and check for Inner_Pred annotations covering current Token

c) If returned AnnotationSet for Inner_Pred is empty, create a new Annotation Outer_Verb with boundaries from b)

Comment: Thanks. A question is how to write the JAPE rule that can "b) take start and stop nodes of this Token and check for Inner_Pred annotations covering current Token". Could you give a simple example, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is source code of JAPE rule:

```
Phase:  Verb
Input: Token
Options: control = appelt
Macro:VERB
(
  ({Token.category==VBD}|{Token.category==VBG}|{Token.category==VBN}|{Token.category==VBP}|{Token.category==VB}|{Token.category==VBZ})
)
Rule:Verb
(
 (VERB)
):verb

-->
{
AnnotationSet set = (AnnotationSet) bindings.get("verb");
Node startNode = set.firstNode();
Node stopNode = set.lastNode();
AnnotationSet innerAnnotations = outputAS.get(startNode.getOffset(), stopNode.getOffset()).get("Inner_Pred");
if (innerAnnotations == null || innerAnnotations.isEmpty()) {
outputAS.add(startNode, stopNode, "Outer_Pred", Factory.newFeatureMap());
}
}
```